# Datatables column select filtering - how to disable filtered out values in select box?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using the datatables.net example [Individual column searching (select inputs)](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) with the example javascript to append SELECT menus into the footer:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api()
                .columns()
                .every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
 
                            column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                        });
 
                    column
                        .data()
                        .unique()
                        .sort()
                        .each(function (d, j) {
                            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                        });
                });
        },
    });
});
```

**Question**:
how to modify the JavaScript to dynamically change the filter SELECT menus to only show values from the filtered selection. For example, after selecting Tokyo it should now limit "Position" to "Accountant, Integration Specialist, Support Engineer, Regional Marketing":
[image]

(Disabling the "invalid" select values would be an option as well using `<option value="..." disabled>...</option>`)

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier  can be applied to get values of filtered data  column(columnid, {search:'applied'} ).data() but I don't see how to apply that in above function

Comment: Just my personal opinion, but I would avoid trying to do this, unless you can specify the drop-downs are truly nested or dependent (and even then it's messy). For example, let's assume the Position drop-down only shows the 4 values you want. And you select one. What does the Office drop-down show? Just Tokyo? All cities? How do you restore seeing all cities? What if the user chose Position (not city) as the first filtering step? The logic is complicated... Unless you can specify some overall behavior, something much simpler than what I think is needed.

Comment: For something sort-of similar, see [Dynamically populate second drop down menu based on first selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68504492/12567365).

Comment: Here is another - it may be of some use, also: [Dynamic filtering values in select elements in Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62224515/12567365).

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! I think the UI issue can be solved by disabling the SELECT values that are not included in the currently filtered page and adding a "reset filter" button.

I'm now trying to use the footerCallback() to get the available values for each of the columns with column_values = api.column( 3, {search:'applied'} ).data().unique()

I'll look at your examples to figure out how to either rebuilt the select boxes or disable the values that have been filtered out

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this for my use case. See @andrewJames comment's above about possible UI issue and how to get around it.
In my use case it works fine to disable SELECT OPTIONS that would result in 0 records shown. I'm also using a ["reset filter" button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40111707/686654)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api()
                .columns()
                .every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    // small change to add ids to the SELECT boxes
                    var column_idx = column.index()
                    var select = $('<select id="column_' + column_idx + '"><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
 
                            column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                        });
 
                    column
                        .data()
                        .unique()
                        .sort()
                        .each(function (d, j) {
                            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                        });
                });
        },
    });
});

// gets called on first load and every time filter or search changes
footerCallback: function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {

    // loop over all columns - hard coded in my example    
    for (var col = 1; col < 15; col++) {                    
        column_id = 'column_' + col
        // retrieve the unique column value after a filter has been applied
        column_values = api.column( col, {search:'applied'} ).data().unique()
        // get the select box by id
        var sel = document.getElementById(column_id)
        // on first page load select box isn't rendered yet
        if (sel != null){
            op = sel.getElementsByTagName('option');
            // disable all select options that are not included in the "available" values
            // we start at 0 because we don't want to disable the blank default                        
            for (var i = 1; i < op.length; i++) {
                if (Array.from(column_values).includes(op[i].value)){
                    op[i].disabled = false
                } else {
                    op[i].disabled = true
                }
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```